# Matching smallest possible group java regexp

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to figure out how to get this regex to work the way I need it to properly. Basically I have a bunch of songs with there lyrics. I am looping through each song lyrics to see if they match the search phrase I am looking for and return the length of the string as like a match rating.

for example I have part of the lyrics of one song here:

```
 "you gave up the love you got & that is that
 she loves me now she loves you not and that where its at"
```

I am using this regexp to find a match:

```
 (?mi)(\bShe\b).*(\bloves\b).*(\byou\b)
```

however it captures this group

```
 "she loves me now she loves you"
```

I want to capture the smallest group possible which would just be "she loves you"

How can I make this capture the smallest group possible?

Some of my code below, I take in the phrase and split it into an array and then check to make sure the lyrics contains the word otherwise we can bail out. I then build a string that will become the regex

```
 static int rankPhrase(String lyrics, String lyricsPhrase){
    //This takes in song lyrics and the phrase we are searching for

    //Split the phrase up into separate words
    String[] phrase = lyricsPhrase.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");

    //Start to build the regex
    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder("(?im)"+"(\\" + "b" + phrase[0] + "\\b)");

    //loop through each word in the phrase
    for(int i = 1; i < phrase.length; i++){

        //Check to see if this word exists in the lyrics first
        if(lyrics.contains(phrase[i])){

            //add this to the regex we will search for
            regex.append(".*(\\b" + phrase[i] + "\\b)");

        }else{
            //if the song isn't found return the rank of 
            //-1 this means song doesn't contain phrase
            return -1;
        }

    }

    //Create the pattern
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex.toString());
    Matcher m = p.matcher(lyrics);


    //Check to see if it can find a match
    if(m.find()){

        //Store this match in a string
        String match = m.group();
```

Comment: CApture all matching groups and select the smallest one?

Comment: You should update your question with 2-3 examples showing what precisely you are trying to capture.  Also please include the relevant Java code.

Comment: thanks, I added some of my code if it helps make sense

Answer (score 2):

```
(\bShe\b)(?:(?!\b(?:she|loves|you)\b).)*(\bloves\b)(?:(?!\b(?:she|loves|you)\b).)*(\byou\b)
```

You can make use of `lookahead` here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/11

For java,use

```
(\\bShe\\b)(?:(?!\\b(?:she|loves|you)\\b).)*(\\bloves\\b)(?:(?!\\b(?:she|loves|you)\\b).)*(\\byou\\b)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try, looks great in the tester

Comment: Looks to be working great. The only other problem I am having is it doesn't seem to go multi line and i have the "im" flags. newline chars are marked as \n

Comment: @CJWeber use `s` flag or instead of `.` use `[\s\S]`

Answer (score 1):

Java's regex matcher only works in the forward direction. What you would need to do is iterate over the set of all matches found and choose the shortest one.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use negative lookahead,

```
Pattern.compile("\\bShe\\b(?:(?!\\bshe\\b).)*?\\bloves\\b(?:(?!\\b(?:you|loves)\\b).)*\\byou\\b");
```